# chunk ran only once knitr/lyx then error

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I am having trouble when I run the following code in lyx, using a script written in R:

```
clean_cache(clean = TRUE)

<<echo=TRUE,results='asis'>>=


library(knitr) 
library(RMySQL) 
library(xtable)

#open mysql database 
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="xxx", password="xxx",dbname="xxx", host="xxx") 

uno<-dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT nhijl FROM resumen where leche;")

#create table
tabla_uno<-data.frame(Total_hijas=round((c(min(uno$nhijl),quantile(uno$nhijl,probs=(0.25)),quantile(uno$nhijl,probs=0.5),mean(uno$nhijl),quantile(uno$nhijl,probs=0.75), max(uno$nhijl))))) 

rownames(tabla_uno)<-(c("Mínimo","1er. cuartil", "Mediana", "Media", "3er. cuartil", "Máximo"))
print(xtable(tabla_uno))
@
```

It seems strange because the first time I ran de code, I had as a result the table I expected, however when I tried a second time, the chunk could not be processed to pdf format.

2 major errors were displayed:

1)

> ! Undefined control sequence. \endkframe ...ip \endMakeFramed
>   \at@end@of@kframe
>
> l.91 \end{kframe}
>                      nhijl

2)

> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{kframe}.
>                                                      l.91 \end{kframe}
>                      nhijl

Your command was ignored.

Can you help me?

Comment: mwe? http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: You might need label too, something like this `<< label = Test, echo = TRUE, results = 'asis' >>=`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, thank you for your suggestions.

I solved the problem by writing the same script directly into lyx.

Is it possible that by copying and pasting the original script from R into lyx, some "invisible rubbish" could have been included and finally caused trouble?

Comment: You might need to paste with ctrl + shift + v, instead of ctrl + v. See the Edit > Paste menu.